# Can my ETH be frozen by Metamask's Validator Staking Contract?

Tags: metamask, wallets, contract-invocation, staking

Does MetaMask have the power to freeze my assets?

I'm not an expert but Validator Staking looks to me like a contract interacting with the beacon chain contract.

Does me investing/interacting into Validator Staking give them the power to freeze my ETH? I'm not judging their reputation here, I'm only interested in a technical answer in case some legislation forces them into doing that.

Is just a theoretical question, not something that happend.

Thanks.

Contract here: https://etherscan.io/address/0xdc71affc862fceb6ad32be58e098423a7727bebd#code